# [Vue warn]: Error in render function: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'matched' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

am trying to route using two routers for two pages,
main.js and profile.js
and 
two init files main and profile

```js
//for main pages
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App';
import MainRouter from './router/main.js';


Vue.config.productionTip = false

/* eslint-disable no-new */
/* vue init for main pages with MainRouter */
new Vue({
  el: '#main-app',
  MainRouter,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { 
    App
  }
})
```

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App';
import ProfileRouter from './router/profile.js'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

/* eslint-disable no-new */
/* vue init for profile pages with profile pages router */
new Vue({
  el: '#profile-app',
  ProfileRouter,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { 
    App
  }
})
```

routers are..

```js
/* Router for main pages */

import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'

/* pages */
import Meeting from '@/components/pages/meeting'
import Feeds from '@/components/pages/feeds'


Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Feeds',
      component: Feeds
    },
    {
      path: '/meeting',
      name: 'Meeting',
      component: Meeting
    },
    {
      path: '/activities',
      name: 'Activities History',
      component: Activities
    },
    {
      path: '/add_member',
      name: 'Add Member',
      component: Add_Member
    }
  ]
})
```

profile.js

```js
/* Router for profile related pages */
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'

/* pages */
import Activities from '@/components/pages/activities_history'
import Change_Password from '@/components/pages/change_password'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Edit Profile',
      component: Edit_Profile
    },
    {
      path: '/activities',
      name: 'Activities History',
      component: Activities
    }
  ]
})
```

ill include more codes if needed...
it was working fine while there was only one router.
can u troubleshoot issue.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you add the router to your Vues you *must* use the name `router`.

```
new Vue({
  el: '#main-app',
  router: MainRouter,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { 
    App
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#profile-app',
  router: ProfileRouter,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { 
    App
  }
})
```

Vue has no idea what a `ProfileRouter` or a `MainRouter` are. It's important to remember that the syntax

```
{ router }
```

is shorthand for

```
{ router: router }
```

which was something that was [introduced with ES2015](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

Comment: thanx bro.. works well

Comment: done :) . i have no reputation.. so accepting